# How to use np.where with a column name as one of the values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

| ID | State | TYPE | START DATE | END DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 863 | MI | Hire | 9/01/23 |  |
| 224 | WI | Retire | 9/01/23 |  |
| 567 | FL | Transfer | 10/01/23 | 10/31/23 |
| 345 | NC |  |  |  |
| 432 | NY |  |  |  |

I have this code:

```
c1 = df["END DATE"].isnull()
c2 = df["TYPE"] == "Hire"
c3 = df["TYPE"] == "Retire"

df = df.copy(deep = True)

x = datetime.datetime.strptime("2023" + "-" + "12" + "-" + "31", '%Y-%m-%d').date()
df["END DATE"] = np.where(((c2 | c3) & c1) , x, df["END DATE"])
```

I get this output:

|  | ID | State | TYPE | START DATE | END DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 863 | MI | Hire | 2023-09-01 | 2023-12-31 |
| 1 | 224 | WI | Retire | 2023-09-01 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2 | 567 | FL | Transfer | 2023-10-01 | 1698710400000000000 |
| 3 | 345 | NC | NaN | NaT | None |
| 4 | 432 | NY | NaN | NaT | None |

The value for the "Transfer" TYPE is messed up. The intention was for it to be unchanged. I know that the issue is due to passing the entire column to `np.where`

1. Is there anyway fix this and still use `np.where` to maintain the `df["END DATE"]` value for that row if the condition is false?
2. If 1. is not possible, what alternative and efficient can I use to put an arbitrary end date where the `"TYPE"` is `"Retire"` or `"Hire"` and the `"END DATE"` is blank?

Comment: Do you have to use `np.where()`? Can't you do `df[df[c2 | c3) & c1]]["END DATE"] = x`?

Comment: You can just replace the rows you selected.  `df.loc((c2|c3)&c1, 'END DATE']) = datetime.date(2023,12,31)`.

Comment: Just correcting  the brackets in the comment  `df.loc[((c2|c3)&c1), 'END DATE'] = datetime.date(2023,12,31)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough copying and pasting your code gave me the expected result. But in your code, the time I believe is correct but it is using unix time. You can enforce the datetime format and that should give you the expected answer.

```
c1 = df["END DATE"].isnull()
c2 = df["TYPE"] == "Hire"
c3 = df["TYPE"] == "Retire"

df = df.copy(deep = True)

x = datetime.datetime.strptime("2023" + "-" + "12" + "-" + "31", '%Y-%m-%d').date()
y = pd.to_datetime(df['END DATE']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# y = df['END DATE']
df["END DATE"] = np.where(((c2 | c3) & c1) , x, y)
```

Now looking at the df gives:

|  | ID | State | TYPE | START DATE | END DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 863 | MI | Hire | 9/01/23 | 2023-12-31 |
| 1 | 224 | WI | Retire | 9/01/23 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2 | 567 | FL | Transfer | 10/01/23 | 2023-10-31 |
| 3 | 345 | NC | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 432 | NY | NaN | NaN | NaN |

You can change the format of the `END DATE` by passing different formats to `dt.strftime`.

Comment: thank you. Does this mean we can pass columns to np.where() and get the right result? I thought we could not pass a whole column or series. @spo

Comment: I have not run into issues when passing columns. If you run into problems you can always convert the columns into numpy arrays with `df['END DATE'].values`. There is also a pandas version of `np.where`. Check out the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html